# Change LightDM session name entries for Desktop Environments?

Tags: unity, gnome, lightdm, session

When using LightDM, sessions, (not usernames) are named in a way I would like to change, for example, Ubuntu is Unity 3D, and I would like to name it that way, the following to:

- Ubuntu 2d to Unity 2D.
- GNOME to Gnome Shell.
- Gnome Fallback to Gnome Classic (Compiz).
- Gnome Fallback (No effects) to Gnome Classic (Light).

Is there any way to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names are taken from the `Name` field in the desktop files located in the `/usr/share/xsessions` directory.

Change them and you're done.