# How to change the badges for the xsessions in LightDM?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, desktop-environments, session, unity-greeter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change circular icon to indicate chosen session in unity-greeter (lightdm)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121352/change-circular-icon-to-indicate-chosen-session-in-unity-greeter-lightdm)

In LightDM, the sessions now display a "badge" with a logo for the xsessions, but badges available are limited to KDE, GNOME, Unity, and Recovery Console. Any other session displayed will use the "unknown_badge.png" file (which is only a blank plain circle), as found on "/usr/share/unity-greeter".

However, I want to get new badges to work on other common sessions, like XBMC Standalone, XFCE4, and Razor-Qt mostly, (also this would be ideal for LXDE, E17, Openbox and other DE users).

I made my own example badge for XBMC, saved the file on "/usr/share/unity-greeter".
Still though, I cannot figure out how to make LightDM or the Unity-Greeter to select that badge to the specific xsession file.

Any help?