# how to change the lightdm gtk session icon

Tags: icons, lightdm, login-screen

Quick question - I'm using lightdm-gtk-greeter in both 15.10 and 16.04

In the panel the budgie-desktop session icon is appearing as a spanner (wrench) icon.

Any ideas how I can change this from this default?

[image]

---

According to this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121352/how-to-change-circular-icon-to-indicate-chosen-session-in-unity-greeter) for the unity-greeter icons are defined in `/usr/share/unity-greeter`

No such folder exists for the lightdm-gtk-greeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightdm-gtk-greeter uses a different icon set. This [question on launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/lightdm-gtk-greeter/+question/252525) explains the naming theme for the icons. I'm using lubuntu 14.04 and the aforementioned icons are located in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/places`.

If you already have an icon (svg file) you want to use, move it to that location and name it `sessionname_badge-symbolic.svg` where sessionname is the name of your session (the session name is found in `/usr/share/xsessions`), budgie in your case. Make sure to update the icon cache afterwards or the greeter still won't use it.

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor
```

That should be it.

If that doesn't work, your icons may be in a different location, or there may not be a conf file for the particular session in `/etc/lightdm`. See the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf file` and [LightDM - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) for more details on writing up a .conf file. Hope this helps.